# How to update a variable before tableView is called

Tags: ios, swift

In the code snippet below, `SecondViewController` is opened via a segue from the `FirstViewController`(first view controller's content not provided as not relevant to the problem). `SecondViewController` contains a tableView but it's empty when displayed (`serviceMain` array), I have verified calling the array within tableView function and the array is indeed empty (`print(serviceMain.count)`) in `B` block comment. However `serviceMain` is actually not empty when constructed and called in `ViewDidLoad` (`A` block comment).

Instead of `ViewDidLoad`, I have tried `ViewWillAppear` which produced the same result.

I'm sure there must be something to do with how segues work, as I can pass the data from `FirstViewController` with `prepare(for segue:sender:)` which I have done with `companyName` and this data is fine. I could update `serviceMain` from within `FirstViewController` and pass the data to `SecondViewController`, but I'm hoping I might be missing something and it can be done within the `SecondViewController`. Many Thanks to all

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var serviceMain: [Service] = []
    var companyName: String = "" // this value is updated with prepare from another ViewController via segue

    @IBOutlet var mobileTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Service.parseData(providerName: companyName, id: 999) { (services: [Service]) in
            for service in services {
                self.serviceMain.append(service)
            }
            // (A) - serviceMain.count is returning a correct value:
            print("number of elements in serviceMain", serviceMain.count, "calling in viewDidLoad")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // (B) - serviceMain.count is returning 0:
        print("number of elements in serviceMain", serviceMain.count, "calling in tableView:")
        return serviceMain.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = mobileTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mobileServiceCell", for: indexPath)
        let serviceIndividualRow = serviceMain[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = serviceIndividualRow.name!

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a didSet. This is called as soon as it is "set", before and viewDidLoad, viewWillLoad etc.

```
var companyName: String? = "" {
    didSet {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

**EDIT TO THE COMMENT YOU MADE ABOUT EXPERIENCING A DELAY:**

When you fetch your data, you might want to try adding your *fetching data* code inside of this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    // FETCH DATA FROM SERVER
}
```

Also, to speed things up, wherever you're reloading your tableViews / collectionViews, you might want to add it inside of this like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Great this actually worked, it was `serviceMain`, I have moved the code block from `ViewDidLoad` to `didSet` and it made the trick. Although there is a tiny bit of time lag, list is empty at first and then updated. It's due to the fact that the data comes from a server. This is a solution for the time being, or do you think i should really send the ready data from `FirstViewController` to avoid the time lag, if there is no other solution for doing things in `SecondViewController`

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help. In my experience, cutting corners when it comes to fetching data anywhere other than the device it's on is a bad move. I'd stick to fetching data again instead of passing it through. No matter what, because it has to be fetched, you'll have a slight delay. To improve it anything from a few seconds to a few milliseconds, you might want mess about with threads. Try adding all of your fetching data code inside of this: 

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { // HERE }

Comment: Check out my updated answer above for a clear answer. If this answer helped you out, I'd appreciate the vote ;)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel - you saved hours of frustration! I will try your suggestion re speed improvements, but it's barely 0.5 sec at the moment, so not too bad for starters